# Android Annotations generates classes but dagger2 @Module classes fails to access those classes

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, dagger-2, android-annotations

I am using Android annotations `4.6.0` and Dagger2 `2.25.2`. I updated my gradle plugin version to 3.5.2. Android annotations library is generating classes for all Activities and Fragments, I am able to see code in generated classes. So If files/classes exists there then why Dagger is failing to access them? Please check below error.

> dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this
>   interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check
>   for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.

Example: For MainActivity it is generating MainActivity_.

Android annotations `4.6.0` and Dagger2 `2.25.2` These libraries are working fine with gradle version plugin `3.3.2`. So Am I missing something, Is there any workaround for this issue? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use

```
dependencies{
...
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
}
```